# How to declare C blocks (or callbacks) using C++ template?

Tags: c++, c, block, objective-c-blocks, return-type

It could be done to declare a function using C++ template like this:

```
template <class T>
T function_A (T input){
    printf("function_A has been called.");
    return input;
}
```

But is it possible to define a C block (or callback) type which using C++ template to declare the return type? For example:

```
template <class T>
typedef T (^Block)(T input);
```

How can I do that (using Obj-C++ if needed)?

Comment: What's a "C block"? That's not a standard term, and you need to define it.

Comment: @KerrekSB [blocks: docs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_(C_language_extension))

Comment: (still better blocks than Code::Blocks)

Comment: seems there ought to be a tag "C block" or similar. What do you want to achieve in plain C++ terms? Can you not use a lambda?

Comment: You cannot template a typedef. You can template a "`using`" type alias in C++11.